# Why cant unittest.TestCases see my py.test fixtures?

Tags: python, unit-testing, fixtures, pytest, python-unittest

I'm trying to use `py.test`'s [fixtures](https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html) with my unit tests, in conjunction with `unittest`. I've put several fixtures in a `conftest.py` file at the top level of the project (as described [here](https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#shifting-visibility-of-fixture-functions)), decorated them with `@pytest.fixture`, and put their names as arguments to the test functions that require them.

The fixtures are registering correctly, as shown by `py.test --fixtures test_stuff.py`, but when I run `py.test`, I get `NameError: global name 'my_fixture' is not defined`. This appears to only occur when I use subclasses of `unittest.TestCase`—but the `py.test` docs seem to say that it plays well with `unittest`.

Why can't the tests see the fixtures when I use `unittest.TestCase`?

---

### Doesn't work:

#### conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
    return 'This is some fixture data'
```

#### test_stuff.py

```
import unittest
import pytest

class TestWithFixtures(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_with_a_fixture(self, my_fixture):
         print(my_fixture)
```

---

### Works:

#### conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture()
def my_fixture():
    return 'This is some fixture data'
```

#### test_stuff.py

```
import pytest

class TestWithFixtures:

    def test_with_a_fixture(self, my_fixture):
         print(my_fixture)
```

---

I'm asking this question more out of curiosity; for now I'm just ditching `unittest` altogether.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> While pytest supports receiving fixtures via test function arguments
>   for non-unittest test methods, unittest.TestCase methods cannot
>   directly receive fixture function arguments as implementing that is
>   likely to inflict on the ability to run general unittest.TestCase test
>   suites.

From the note section at the bottom of:
https://pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html

It's possible to use fixtures with `unittest.TestCase`es. See that page for more information.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the pytest fixtures in `unittest.TestCase` with the pytest option `autouse`. However, if you use the `test_`  for the unit method using the fixture the following error will appear:

`Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,...`

```
### conftest.py
@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
    return 'This is some fixture data'
```

One solution is to use a `prepare_fixture` method to set fixtures as an attribute of the `TestWithFixtures` class, so that fixtures are available to all unit test methods.

```
### test_stuff.py
       
import unittest
import pytest
    
class TestWithFixtures(unittest.TestCase):
    

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def prepare_fixture(self, my_fixture):
        self.myfixture = my_fixture

    def test_with_a_fixture(self):
        print(self.myfixture)
```

Comment: This just fails with the error `Fixture "test_with_a_fixture" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly, ...`

Comment: this examples doesn't work!

Answer (score 5):

1. define the fixture as an accessible variable, (like `input` in the following example). To define it, use `request.cls.VARIABLE_NAME_YOU_DEFINE = RETURN_VALUE`
2. use `@pytest.mark.usefixtures("YOUR_FIXTURE")` to use fixture outside of the unittest class, inside the unittest class, access the fixture by `self.VARIABLE_NAME_YOU_DEFINE`.

e.g.

```
import unittest
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def test_input(request):
    request.cls.input = {"key": "value"}


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("test_input")
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_something(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.input["key"], "value")
```

Comment: Can the fixture be written outside of the test class with "session" scope ?